# Can I make a Material Navigation Drawer and FAB in Qt?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm new to Qt, I downloaded v 5.7 with Quick Controls 2.0 mainly for Android development and I was wondering if there is a possibility to use some material controls like sliding navigation drawer and floating action button given their ubiquitousness now (e.g. twitter app lately).

Thanks.

Comment: The new controls are generally meant to ease embedded/mobile development. Differently from previous controls they provide a built-in [Drawer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-controls-drawer.html) and swipe-able areas (see [SwipeView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-controls-swipeview.html) which were missing in previous controls. There is no default implantation for the floating action button, instead. You can find a lot of user-implementations though, or easily create one yourself.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Ok glad to know it's possible, is it like native? any references on that? and also I can see SwipeView in the QML types.

Comment: Granted it is not native, it looks like  it is, thanks to the styling, and it works in a similar way (see the linked documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Drawer` from Qt quick controls 2.0. I was also searching for a application drawer and [here it is](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html).

To help you out I've cook a simple example. Paste it in your `main.qml` and give it a run.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick 2.7

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 480
    height: 640
    visible: true

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: window.width/2
        height: window.height
        Rectangle{
            Column{
                spacing: 5
                Label{
                    text:"Awesome"
                }
                Label{
                    text:"Awesome"
                }
                Label{
                    text:"Awesome"
                }
                Label{
                    text:"Awesome"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Label{
            id:label
            text:"Yeah Label is awesome"
        }
        Rectangle{
            id: rectangle
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color:"Red"
            height: parent.height/2
            width: parent.width/2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt Quick Controls 2.1, since the Qt 5.8 release, has a QML type called [`RoundButton`](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-roundbutton.html), which has an elevation effect in the Material style. It is demonstrated as a *Floating Action Button* in the [Text Editor Example](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-texteditor-example.html):

[image: Qt Quick Controls 2 - Text Editor Example]